# Questions "Is there data of X" / "Looking for data of X"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I think that for all questions looking for particular data (as opposed to questions e.g. asking for the legal side of data) there should be a tag .g. [data-hunt](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-hunt), or at least there should be a good convention for titles.

For me a question which is "Is there a complete data for X?" the right answer is "Yes." or "No.".

It's StackExchange. If someone wants to ask for sth, it is the best when it is done in a direct ways.

Answer (score 20):

I would suggest using the same 'request' tag convention used by other sites… something like:

[data-request](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request)

Feel free to suggest a better term for 'data', but I suggest following the basic [*-request] nomenclature.

Comment: Do you have an example of this *-request tags? I have never seen it, beside on meta sites. But why not, it sounds good.

Comment: @Vince http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request, http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/tagged/data-request, http://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app-request, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-request, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-request, http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request

Comment: interesting. [tag:data-request] or [tag:dataset-request] sound pretty good then.

Comment: if -request is conventional, then I think data-request is a good suggestion. dataset-request is longer for no added value.

Comment: for what I have seen, I would suggest [tag:geodata-request] [tag:tool-request]

Comment: I like data-hunt or data-search, simply because data-request sounds like it includes asking if a person or organization would release the data.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with you, I think there should be such a tag, to differentiate from some [tools](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) questions for example.

I would go more for [dataset](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dataset), simple [data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) or even [resources](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources).

And I agree, all such questions may better have the title "What machine-readable data is available for ..." or "Which dataset provide information about ...".

Comment: `data` sounds too generic, but `dataset` looks great.

Answer (score 2):

## title, text, and tagging conventions

I believe it would be easier to read through a list of "Where can I find X:" questions if there was a clear, minimalist title that provides key features required to identify data like:

> Pigs (in space, pounds / year ) ?

With the units and scope in parantheses, and the question to indicate that they are looking. Perhaps there could be a "binocular" icon to represent "looking for".

Since many users will never see this post, when someone puts the phrase "I find" in the title field, a helpful notice could appear suggestings whatever conventions are adopted.

In addition, I think that there could be suggestions for relevant information that will help others provide useful answers, both in the text and tags. There is likely a set of key information (what where when ...) that could be requested, and this could make use of tags for categories and scopes of data.

Going off on a limb ... text and tags information could be used to search meta=-data of open data sets as the question is being typed ...

Comment: Also, I think license and format requirements should be specified.