# Is data collection on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Example: [Building a Sentiment Analysis Dictionary for a Non-English Language](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/86/building-a-sentiment-analysis-dictionary-for-a-non-english-language)

Most questions here are about retrieval or processing of data. Should data compiling be considered on-topic?

Personally, I would like to see the site focusing on use of open data, because data collection is a vast and rather different area.

Comment: As long as the question is about collecting *open* data, what's the harm?

Comment: Do you include data extraction techniques in data collection? or don't you consider the techniques?

Comment: @Vince What I meant by data collection is collection of raw data (conducting surveys, developing Internet crawlers, for example). Extracting information from an already existing data set is not what I intended to include.

Comment: See also the related discussion at [Will we allow questions that deal with computational linguistics corpora?](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/26/will-we-allow-questions-that-deal-with-computational-linguistics-corpora)

Comment: @AndyShuXin Note that my answer involves extracting/synthesizing new data sets *using existing data sets*.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably vote to close something purely about data collection. I think information about sources and about how to use sources is on topic.

I'm also kind of receptive to posts about best practices about publishing data, but I still think collection is a step too far out.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it should be closed. I think we should look at the bigger picture. Open Data is quite focused on the "open" part, so on the release and collection of data. There was a short [discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9361/similar-proposal-to-data) talking a bit about it.

There is a growing data.SE project, SO and some other projects probably have many questions on the topic of analysing and manipulating data (even though I don't know how wide the scope of your "use" is).

But I agree that there is a large part of the questions that will cover data collection, and it should not pollute the rest of the site. That's why we should tag them properly (and maybe have a template). There is another [discussion about it](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/questions-is-there-data-of-x-looking-for-data-of-x).

Comment: Ah, pardon me for my vague wording. I meant to point out that the example question is about construction of a data set that doesn't previously exist. While other data-collection questions are about locating data sets that does (presumably) exist.

Comment: @AndyShuXin Ok I see. I guess I'll rephrase my entire answer.