# real-time suggestions for text, title, and tagging conventions on "where can I find data on ..." questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am not sure how feasible it would be, but I am now reposting the idea as a "feature-request"

Answers to a previous question, [Questions "Is there data of X" / "Looking for data of X"](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/questions-is-there-data-of-x-looking-for-data-of-x) led [me to suggest](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/a/135/1049) that the answers could be summarized and provided as real-time suggestions as a new question is being written.

These suggestions could suggest

- tag, e.g. [data-request](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request)
- useful information, e.g. units, coverage, resolution
- relevant repositories, e.g. "have you searched"...